# Unclear how parameter in sumBy block work (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

This is the answer to a codewars challenge whereby a series of words is passed as a parameter and the word with the highest score is returned, with each letter scoring its corresponding alphabet position.

```
str.split(' ').maxBy{ it.sumBy{ it - 'a' + 1 } }!!
```

I understand what's happening here except for the "- 'a' " in the `sumBy` block.

Can someone maybe explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

It's an old trick that takes advantage of the fact that most (all?) character encodings have the English letters in alphabetic order and consecutive. [Here's an example of an ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.xyz/).

As you can see, `'a'` has a given number value. This is the value you obtain if you convert the character to a number in Kotlin (which is implicitly done in the code you provided). If you substract it (`it - 'a'`) you will get 0 for `'a'`, 1 for `'b'`, 2 for `'c'` and so on. This is their alphabet position by an offset of one, which is why there's a +1 that fixes that offset, so now `it - 'a' + 1` returns a number such as `'a'` = 1, `'b'` = 2, etc...

Note that this trick will not work for non-English alphabets.

Comment: It's not just that they're in order; they're also consecutive, which is why this works.  (Note that Java's native character set is Unicode, encoded as UTF-16.  So `'a'` is 97, `'b'` is 98, and so on.  So the effect of this is to subtract 96 from the character code to get the alphabet position; you could use `{ it - 96 }`, though that would be less clear.)